# Getting rid of AC DC adapters

Tags: power, wire, adapter

[Getting rid of AC/DC adapters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34557/getting-rid-of-ac-dc-adapters)
I'm aware of the above question but feel it didn't address my situation.

Note: Robot meant to be an underwater ROV(Remotely operated vehicle)

I'm designing a robot and using a KVM extender (so receiver on the bot and transmitter underwater near my controller). I have an issue powering the KVM on the bot. Basically, I have a Power Distribution Block on the bot to power the various other things on there and it would be nice to hook up the KVM to that too. However, the KVM's cable has an AC-DC adapter on it (so while the KVM is DC the cable has been made under the assumption that it will be connected to an outlet).

KVM I'm using: [https://www.amazon.com/Extender-Transmit-Ethernet-Keyboard-Control/dp/B08K2MXBPR/ref=sr_1_6?crid=YYOV7AHJ6RXU&keywords=kvm+extender&qid=1643761712&sprefix=kvm+extender%2Caps%2C194&sr=8-6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08K2MXBPR)

Is it possible to "chop off" the AC-DC adapter and feed the remaining cables into various spade connectors and attach those spade connectors to the Power Distribution Block?

If so, how would the process go? Things to watch out for and the like.

If not, are there any other things I can try (space is an issue on the bot so solutions that do not require another sizable component would be ideal)? Thanks!

P.S I have access to heat shrinks so bare wires would not be an issue.

Edit: I forgot to mention but yes the PDB is 12V

Comment: Don't lose track of which wire is which. I wouldn't cut the cable. Make your own.

Comment: Assuming you have 12v, yes you can ditch the AC->12vDC converter and supply 12v directly.

Comment: why do you require the use of a KVM extender? ... btw, calling it just KVM is unclear, because there is such a thing as a KVM switch ... it's like saying `I have a box of red` when you are talking about apples

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for the insight. The reason I'm using an extender is because I'd like to control my robot with wired connection with a controller(so I would have the controller hooked up to the transmitter and the receiver hooked up to a Raspberry Pi which is in charge of onboard operations).

Comment: you could possibly do the same by using an ethernet cable without any extender

Comment: @jsotola I did look into that but I realized that I had too many things to do that(I have cameras on the robot and would like to a live feed). And there will be a GUI on the Pi(so I'd like to use a mouse from land to interact with that).

Comment: VNC is basically a KVM done in software, except it's switchable and routeable

Answer (score 0):

I can’t see the power inlet on the KVM but it’s quite common for 12V devices to use a 2.1mm DC jack.  If you have a 12V source then I would recommend making up a suitable cable - the middle pin is almost always positive and there may be a diagram next to the power inlet on the device itself.  This way you can keep the AC/DC adapter in case you need it again.

Answer (score 0):

The KVM expects 12V DC. If your power block has 12V and you can provide the current required to the KVM as well as your other components, then that's half the battle. It's literally just matching positive to positive for the connector.

The KVM may regulate down internally. You could tell by looking inside the box. That would be best. It would help filter out issues from any motors or relays your bot may be using. A high speed digital signal product may not like a lot of noise on the line. Another thing to look out for is brown outs. If your supply can't keep up with the current demands it could cause the KVM to disconnect. You could add a large capacitor (1000 or 2000 ųF) at the kvm power to help compensate.